# How to allow header field (HeaderParam) when using the MARS REST API Library with Delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi, cors, fetch-api, request-headers

I've made a basic API using the [MARS-Curiosity Delphi REST Library](https://github.com/andrea-magni/MARS) with a POST Request Endpoint and this endpoint is working perfectly fine in [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), but as soon as I try to do the POST Request from somewhere else such as within JavaScript, then I get a CORS policy error.

Here's exactly what I get:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/person/profile/get' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field api_key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/person/profile/get net::ERR_FAILED

[image: Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/person/profile/get' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field api_key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.]

I am not sure how to allow or use headers within MARS. I tried looking at the demos, but I didn't find anything helpful.

This is my Delphi code where I define the endpoint:

```
[Path('profile')]
TPersonResource = class
protected
public
  [POST, Path('get'), Produces(TMediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)]
  function PersonProfileGet([HeaderParam] API_Key: String; [BodyParam] APerson: TPersonGet): TArray<TPersonGet>;
end;
```

You'll see I have `[HeaderParam] API_Key: String;` as one of the parameters in the `PersonProfileGet` function. This is how it is done in some of the [Demos](https://github.com/andrea-magni/MARS/tree/master/Demos) also.

And this is the JavaScript code I am using to try and do the request from:

```
const requestHeaders = {
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
    "API_Key": "Test"
};

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: requestHeaders
};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/person/profile/get", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Does anyone know how to allow header fields in MARS or why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS when using the MARS REST API Library with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76665671/how-to-enable-cors-when-using-the-mars-rest-api-library-with-delphi)

Comment: @EirikA. No, it didn't. My issue was that I didn't have `API_Key` set as an allowed Header. I need to just append it to my `.ini` file under `CORS.Headers`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple.

There's a `.ini` file in the same folder as your executable. It should also have the same name as your executable.

If you add the following line in there:

```
CORS.Headers=API_Key
```

This will allow `API_Key` to be used as one of the header fields.

But in your case, `CORS.Headers` is already in there with some allowed headers already set seeing that `Content-Type` was allowed and didn't give a CORS policy error. So you just need to find `CORS.Headers` and then add `API_Key` at the end of it, like in this example:

```
CORS.Headers=Content-Type,API_Key
```

Comment: What - this cannot be changed programmatically? Also: why are you refering to yourself as "_in_your_case_"?

Comment: @AmigoJack Hmmmm. Good question. 

I think it might be possible to change it programmatically. I'll do some research and see if it's possible or not and how to do it. Then I'll update my answer and add that if it's possible. 

Also: I'm referring in that way because I believe this is the recommended way when you're asking and answering your own question as described here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.215710356.225715383.1689627428-1400841231.1685332886